# Linux: Add Virtual Interface for KVM

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

On a CentOS server, `ifconfig` shows several vnetX interfaces (vent1, vent2, vent100), how can I add some more?

(I'd like to add a couple of virtual machines, so I need to add some more virtual interfaces that I can assign to the virtual machines).

Also, from what I understand, these vnetX interface are internal, between the host and virtual guest, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these are set up on the VM level, you assign NICs to a VM, and it starts with them, creating vnetX NICs in the process.

As for how the networking is set up, just search for "libvirt bridge" and "libvirt NAT"

Answer (score 0):

Why not use bridge mode in KVM for the Guest machines.

Comment: Because that's how this VM host is already set up, so I'd like to add to it in the same way it has been set up.

Answer (score 0):

I think he is probably using bridge mode, check this typing **brctl show**. If there is one bridge, you can add extra interfaces using tunctl tool.

Like this: **tunctl -u root -t interfaceNameX**